# Connection error while installing react native cli via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm-install

I have been going step by step by the official instructions that are on [react native site](https://archive.reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started) in the dev OS I have Windows and in the target OS I have Android. The installation via choco went well but when I try installing it with:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

it starts normal like this:
[image: [..................] \ idealTree:npm: sill idealTree buildDeps]
but then after a while it returns just these errors:
[image: errors]

I have already tried changing proxy and making it "the right way" but it just keeps crashing like this. Btw I have proxy on http://domain:8080/

Any ideas how to fix this pls?

Comment: Have you configured your proxy with npm?

npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution was very simple. If someone has same problem as this and is sure they are not on proxy, try pinging ipv6 address. If it doesn't answer then there is the issue. Just unclick ipv6 and it will work just fine.